# keystroke util, keyboard callback problem

Tags: winapi, keyboard, callback

I got this idea a long time ago when i saw an app do this for a game.

i want to catch certain keystrokes. Something like /s myCommand. I had ppl msg me and mess me up through msn so my first command would be something like killmsn. I looked up the resource on msdn and got this far. This doesnt work, why doesnt it? is it BC of sleep? how else should i do this, note i dont have a window and i want this to be a console app. my KeyboardProc is NEVER called

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

HHOOK hook;
LRESULT CALLBACK KeyboardProc(int code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    printf("%c", wParam);
    return CallNextHookEx(hook, code, wParam, lParam);
}

int main()
{
    hook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD, KeyboardProc, GetModuleHandle(0), 0);
    Sleep(10000);
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(hook);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution

```
//Sleep(10000);
MSG msg;
while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
{
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
}
UnhookWindowsHookEx(hook);
```